# Berksfile source doesn't recognize self-hosted Chef server

Tags: chef, berkshelf

I have a self-hosted Chef server. I can `knife upload` to that server, and otherwise interact with it. Therefore, my `knife.rb` works fine. I have recently parameterized a cookbook in order to make it the basis for a family of related cookbooks.

The problem is that I want this cookbook to be private, so it only exists on my private Chef server. Unfortunately, I can't then do `berks install` on my other cookbooks. I've pointed my `Berksfile` at my Chef server:

`source https://chef.myhost.com`

This does not work. I *think* this is because that URL is for Chef Manage, not Chef Server API. However, I am at a loss for how to get Berkshelf to recognize my Chef Server and use its API.

The full error:

```
> berks install
Resolving cookbook dependencies...
Fetching 'blog_role' from source at .
Fetching cookbook index from chef.myhost.com...
Error retrieving universe from source: chef.myhost.com * [Berkshelf::APIClient::BadResponse] bad response #<Faraday::Response:0x36ae618 @on_complete_callbacks=[], @env=#<Faraday::Env @method=:get @body="<html><body>You are being <a href=\"chef.myhost.com:443/signup\">redirected</a>.</body></html>" @url=#<URI::HTTPS:0x36891f0 URL:chef.myhost.com/universe> @request=#<Faraday::RequestOptions timeout=30, open_timeout=30> @request_headers={"User-Agent"=>"Faraday v0.9.1"} @ssl=#<Faraday::SSLOptions (empty)> @response_headers={"server"=>"ngx_openresty/1.4.3.6", "date"=>"Sun, 08 Feb 2015 19:49:10 GMT", "content-type"=>"text/html; charset=utf-8", "transfer-encoding"=>"chunked", "connection"=>"close", "status"=>"302 Found", "strict-transport-security"=>"max-age=631138519", "x-frame-options"=>"DENY", "x-webkit-csp"=>"default-src 'self' chrome-extension:; connect-src 'self' chrome-extension:; font-src 'self' themes.googleusercontent.com chrome-extension:; frame-src 'none' chrome-extension:; img-src 'self' ssl.google-analytics.com chrome-extension: data:; media-src 'none' chrome-extension:; object-src 'none' chrome-extension:; script-src 'self' ssl.google-analytics.com 'unsafe-inline' chrome-extension:; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' fonts.googleapis.com chrome-extension:; script-nonce REDACTED;", "x-xss-protection"=>"1", "location"=>"chef.myhost.com:443/signup", "x-ua-compatible"=>"IE=Edge,chrome=1", "cache-control"=>"no-cache", "set-cookie"=>"chef-manage=REDACTED; path=/; secure; HttpOnly", "x-request-id"=>"REDACTED", "x-runtime"=>"0.034395"} @status=302>>
Unable to satisfy constraints on package source_deploy, which does not exist, due to solution constraint (app_role = 0.9.1). Solution constraints that may result in a constraint on source_deploy: [(app_role = 0.9.1) -> (source_deploy >= 0.0.0)]
Missing artifacts: source_deploy
Demand that cannot be met: (app_role = 0.9.1)
Unable to find a solution for demands: app_role (0.9.1)
```

So, it tries to access https://chef.myhost.com/universe, but it is bounced to the /signup page, because this is Chef Manage, not Chef Server API... But I have no idea where the API is accessible from by default, if at all. I've read for the past hour various docs, and turned up nothing...

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that the `source` in a `Berksfile` is actually the URL of a *Berkshelf API Server*, **not** a *Chef Server API*.

After doing `gem install berkshelf-api` and configuring the `config.json` to use my Chef Server as an endpoint, I was able to run `berks-api` and then use port 26200 on my Chef Server as the target of the `source` in the `Berksfile`.

From here, `berks install` and `berks upload` both worked.

Comment: Where (which server) did you run the gem install berkshelf-api? I assume your config.json changes are in the workstation running berks install/upload? Where (what server) did you run berks-api? I'm trying to set this up myself and having the same issues. In my case I set up a berks-api organization on my Chef 12 Enterprise server, which I understand is Berks-API enabled? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue as you. Since updating to a newer version of Chef Server and Chef DK in an environment re-roll I went to using berkshelf for dependency management.

My **metadata.rb** file for a cookbook, let's call it **second_local_cookbook** referenced **first_local_cookbook** like this:

```
depends 'first_local_cookbook'
```

Then when I would run:

```
berks install
```

On **second_local_cookbook** to determine cookbook dependencies and the command would fail in the same way as you:

```
Fetching cookbook index from https://supermarket.chef.io...
Unable to satisfy constraints on package first_local_cookbook, which does not exist, due to solution constraint (second_local_cookbook = 0.1.0).
Solution constraints that may result in a constraint on first_local_cookbook: [(second_local_cookbook = 0.1.0) -> (first_local_cookbook >= 0.0.0)]
Missing artifacts: first_local_cookbook
```

I didn't try your solution as I was hoping there was a simple answer to reference local private cookbooks without having to install a new server API. And I found this closed issue in berkshelf's GitHub (https://github.com/berkshelf/berkshelf/issues/892). To reference a local cookbook from another cookbook you merely reference the **first_local_cookbook** in the **Berksfile** of **second_local_cookbook** before the **metadata** area like this:

```
source 'https://api.berkshelf.com'

cookbook 'first_local_cookbook', path: '../first_local_cookbook'
metadata
```

And running berks install would then succeed:

```
berks install
Resolving cookbook dependencies...
Fetching 'first_local_cookbook' from source at ../first_local_cookbook
Fetching 'second_local_cookbook' from source at .
...
```

I can then run the berks upload successfully:

```
berks upload second_local_cookbook --no-freeze
Uploaded second_local_cookbook (0.1.0) to: 'https://chefserver:443/organizations/organization'
```